# PHP - Codeigniter removing dash and brackets while inserting to DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, insert

So I've tried to debug this to some extend but I have no idea why this is happening. So after retrieving info from and excel file I try to database, for the most case this works, but I have 2 exceptions that are giving me a hard time. Firstly a part no. with a "-" is removed while inserting (ex: sxrv-11 becomes sxrv11) in the db and second brackets (ex: (pv) is converted to a 1 so (pv)tr55x would become 1tr55x)

here is an example var_dump of the array:

```
array(20) {
  ["stock_no"]=>
  float(127)
  ["part_no"]=>
  string(9) "SIFR6A-11"
  ["pop_code"]=>
  string(3) "D-N"
  ["jobber"]=>
  float(15.2)
  ["sell_out"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["suggested_qty"]=>
  float(4)
  ["box_qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["case_qty"]=>
  float(120)
  ["description"]=>
  string(50) "LASER IRIDIUM SPARK PLUG / BOUGIE IRIDIUM AU LASER"
  ["individual_upc"]=>
  string(12) "087295101278"
  ["box_upc"]=>
  string(12) "087295001271"
  ["case_upc"]=>
  string(14) "10087295001278"
  ["part_status"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["product_desc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["box_size"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fk_id_brand"]=>
  int(1)
  ["fk_id_category"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["fk_id_subcategory"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["description_en"]=>
  string(24) "laser iridium spark plug"
  ["description_fr"]=>
  string(23) "bougie iridium au laser"
}
```

This is the insert function that uses that data array to insert:

```
public function insert_product($product)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($product);
    echo "</pre>";
    $this->db->set('fk_id_category', $product['fk_id_category']);
    $this->db->set('fk_id_subcategory', $product['fk_id_subcategory']);
    $this->db->set('fk_id_brand', $product['fk_id_brand']);
    $this->db->set('stock_no', $product['stock_no']);
    $this->db->set('part_no', $product['part_no']);
    $this->db->set('pop_code', $product['pop_code']);
    $this->db->set('jobber', $product['jobber']);
    $this->db->set('part_status', $product['part_status']);
    $this->db->set('sell_out', $product['sell_out']);
    $this->db->set('suggested_qty', $product['suggested_qty']);
    $this->db->set('box_qty', $product['box_qty']);
    $this->db->set('case_qty', $product['case_qty']);
    $this->db->set('description_en', $product['description_en']);
    $this->db->set('description_fr', $product['description_fr']);
    $this->db->set('product_desc', $product['product_desc']);
    $this->db->set('box_size', $product['box_size']);
    $this->db->set('individual_upc', $product['individual_upc']);
    $this->db->set('box_upc', $product['box_upc']);
    $this->db->set('case_upc', $product['case_upc']);
    $this->db->insert('product');
}
```

Once in the database it's modified to the examples described before. I've tried different mysql collations and it doesn't change anything.

The oddest part about all this is that the "pop_code" keeps the "-" when inserted in the database. They are both varchar() 20 and 5 respectively.

I can't tell if it's a PHP issue, codeigniter issue, mysql issue, phpmyadmin issue. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: after your ->insert(); add the following die($this->db->last_query()); post the output back here to see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Codeigniter active record insert set()** function will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE. To illustrate the difference, here is set() used both with and without the escape parameter.

Try this : `$this->db->set('part_no', $product['part_no'], FALSE);`

Comment: Ok so setting the parameter as false remove the single quotes around the string and gives me a db error for not recognizing "-". So example 'sss-11' becomes sss-11

Comment: Can you try inserting `$this->db->set('part_no', $product['pop_code']);` ? To see what happen when you insert pop_code value into part_no.

Comment: so the weirdest thing is happening, I set part_no to insert pop_code and it's still adding part_no (the incorrect one).

Comment: I even deleted the line completely, erased the table manually (my code does it with every upload in the first place anyways) and inserting still adds the same part_no I am super confused.

Comment: Are you sure when your form post, it comes to correct controller and action?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your database field data types ,

check columns' data types , if you want to add values with characters change them to `VARCAHR`

try

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR;
```

Also can you describr your table strucure

```
DESCRIBE tableName;
```